# Trying to read a json lines file with OPENROWSET and cursor

Tags: sql-server, json, cursors, openrowset

I've got a pile of json lines files that I'm trying to process into a set of Sql Server database tables.  Can't use OPENJSON() because jsonlines is not valid in total, only line by line.  Plus the files are mammoth so I was trying to work up a way to process it line by line without reading the whole file in as a CLOB and then parsing it.

My first thought was to use OPENROWSET with a format file that declared only one column - one giant string.  Then I was going to put a cursor on that and loop through.

The individual bits are working great, but when I put a cursor on an OPENROWSET like this, the cursor fetches one line and stops (breaks out of the WHILE loop).

I googled for a while but couldn't find anything precisely like this.

Is this an inherent limitation of trying to use OPENROWSET and a cursor together?  Or are there some different cursor options I could use that might handle it better?

I was hoping for an all-in-sql approach, but I suppose I could knock together some script that will read the lines and feed them in a query individually.

Thanks

```
DECLARE @line nvarchar(max)
DECLARE JsonLCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD for
SELECT [Object] FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'G:\input\944.jsonl', FORMATFILE='G:\jsonl.fmt') as j

OPEN JsonLCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM JsonLCursor INTO @Line

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC [dbo].[JsonLProcess] @line = @line
    FETCH NEXT FROM JsonLCursor INTO @Line
END

CLOSE JsonLCursor
DEALLOCATE JSonLCursor
```

JsonL.fmt

```
14.0
1
1   SQLCHAR 0   1000000 "\r\n"  1   Object  Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8
```

Comment: Good point.  My smaller samples were done through notepad++ so the \n -> \r\n might have gotten normalized there.  I just changed the format file to \n and got a lot farther.  If you want to post this as a reply, I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: There should be a neat way to make it into a giant JSON array. What about adding brackets `[]` beginning and end, and perhaps a comma at the end of each line? Either way, you should be able to use `OPENJSON` or whatever code you have in that stored procedure, directly on the `OPENROWSET` result, which would be far easier and perform better. Please add the code for the procedure in the question

Comment: Aaron - I got passed the initial problem and PRINT outputs a number for all of the lines but then it says the query the "Query completed with Errors" and there are some missing rows from the table count.  Charlieface, I could try and dress it up, but the files are almost 700 meg.  I was trying to avoid sucking it all into memory at once.

Comment: Okay, just fixed a couple of errors and got through the full 700 meg file in about 4 3/4 minutes